# Webmail demo for knockout using Typescript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I'm trying to get the last tutorial on knockout to work with Typescript, but can't seem to populate the email grid.

```
class WebmailViewModel {

    folders: any;
    chosenFolderId: any;
    chosenFolderData: any;
    public event_goToFolder: (folder) => void;

    constructor () {

        this.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent'];

        this.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
        this.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();

        this.event_goToFolder = ((folder) => {
            this.chosenFolderId(folder);
            $.get('/mail/' + folder + ".txt", { folder: folder }, this.chosenFolderData);
            // send JSON result to DIV
            $("div#jsond").text(JSON.stringify(this.chosenFolderData()));
        });

        // set default folder
        this.event_goToFolder("Inbox");
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

And my View:

```
    <ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
        <li data-bind="text: $data, css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() }, click: $root.event_goToFolder"></li>
    </ul>

    <table class="mails" data-bind="with: chosenFolderData">
        <thead><tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: mails">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: from"></td>(
                <td data-bind="text: to"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: subject"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
            </tr>     
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="border:4px solid blue" data-bind="text: chosenFolderData"></div>
    <div id="jsond" style="border:4px solid black"></div>
```

When I run the app, I can see the JSON data in the DIV #jsond, but the email grid does not show up as expected, from the demo.

On thing worth mentioning, I am using a TXT file stored locally, with JSON data in it - rather than using an actual Web api of some sort.  However, the JSON data shows up fine in the DIV, so I don't see that as being a problem.

Here is my JSON data:

```
"{\"id\":\"Inbox\",\"mails\":[{\"id\":1,\"from\":\"Abbot <oliver@smoke-stage.xyz>\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"May 25, 2011\",\"subject\":\"Booking confirmation #389629244\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":2,\"from\":\"Addison Begoat <upton.oprdrusson@pear-income.xyz>\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"May 7, 2011\",\"subject\":\"FW: Associate advice\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":3,\"from\":\"Allistair <leroy72@plane-railway.xyz>\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"May 19, 2011\",\"subject\":\"RE: Phone call tomorrow 5 o'clock\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":4,\"from\":\"emmanuel26@ghost.xyz\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"May 22, 2011\",\"subject\":\"Completing basketball project\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":5,\"from\":\"jamalia.alnismith1@twigdad.xyz\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"Apr 26, 2011\",\"subject\":\"FW: Can you get DE to resubmit accounts?\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":6,\"from\":\"lionel.qugy@cribsmoke.xyz\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"May 22, 2011\",\"subject\":\"RE: Catch up at 9:00 to finalise rain spec\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":7,\"from\":\"Madison Lalinesson <melinda.gofagy@wing-language2.xyz>\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"May 19, 2011\",\"subject\":\"RE: Pencil scenarios\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":8,\"from\":\"rajah.nukripyford@cast92.xyz\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"Apr 28, 2011\",\"subject\":\"Flavor benefit gig\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":9,\"from\":\"Sandra Juanhison <yoshi.mostaline72@facefruit.xyz>\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"May 8, 2011\",\"subject\":\"RE: Apparel5 network is back up\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":10,\"from\":\"Sylvester <rose.va@bunpig98.xyz>\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"May 1, 2011\",\"subject\":\"Feedback requested by Ayanna Nuyo\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":11,\"from\":\"veronica@heart.xyz\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"May 4, 2011\",\"subject\":\"Project Book starting 6pm\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"},{\"id\":12,\"from\":\"XLN <basia@framehome.xyz>\",\"to\":\"steve@example.com\",\"date\":\"May 8, 2011\",\"subject\":\"RE: Remember Whoopi's joke\",\"folder\":\"Inbox\"}]}"
```

The actual error that I receive:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: mails is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: mails
```

UPDATE:

I'm following the code pretty much to the letter from the knockout site.  Everything else has worked well up to this point...  Maybe it would help for me to post the actual JS code from the Typescript conversion -

```
var WebmailViewModel = (function () {
    function WebmailViewModel() {
        var _this = this;
        this.folders = [
            'Inbox', 
            'Archive', 
            'Sent'
        ];
        this.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
        this.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();
        this.event_goToFolder = (function (folder) {
            _this.chosenFolderId(folder);
            $.get('/mail/' + folder + ".txt", { folder: folder }, this.chosenFolderData);
        });
        this.event_goToFolder("Inbox");
    }
    return WebmailViewModel;
})();    
; ;
ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be treating this.chosenFolderData as an observable, aren't you just over-writing it with the JSON you return from your get query? What happens if you change it to:

```
$.get('/mail/' + folder + ".txt", { folder: folder }, function(data)
{
    this.chosenFolderData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
});
```

This uses the [Knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Comment: I just gave it a go...but now get the following:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fromJS' of undefined`

Comment: Have you downloaded the mapping plugin and included it in your page? You can get it from https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/tree/master/build/output

Comment: I added the d.ts file for typescript, but like a dummy, forgot to add the js link.  Done, but still get:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__ko_mapping__' of undefined`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you debug it and see what this.chosenFolderData looks like after the data has been retrieved?

Comment: It is a function, but when I call JSON.stringify on it, I see the JSON as shown above in the original post.  I hate to break in the middle - and appreciate your assistance - but heading to a Sprint planning session.  I'll return later to check on updates.  Thank you for your assistance up to now.

Comment: It should be a knockout representation of your json data, so it should have a mails property containing an array. Actually, just had a thought, I'll update the code in my answer.

Comment: Yep, the JSON has a 'mails': [] in there.  I inspected it using JSFiddle.  Now, I could be missing something...perhaps there is something wrong with the data, even though it looks correct???  I'm just scratching my head at this point...

Comment: When it blows up, the debugger should break at the line it's gone wrong, and you should be able to see, at some point in the call stack, what object it thinks that it's binding to.